# Adding WebElement attributes to a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, selenium, element

I am looking to compare dates from a calender to another place to verify the dates are appearing else where after a user has selected them.  I am taking these dates and converting them to another format for the verification.

The problem I am having is when creating the array from the web elements attribute which holds the date information.  I am attempting to iterate though selected dates, then take the attributes, convert it to my format, then add it to a List to review later.

Every time I look at the String List, it is empty.  I figured just using .add() would work but this is not the case.  Even when I println a static string I hardcode to verify collectedDateStrings, I am gettting nothing on the console.

```
List < String > collectedDateStrings = new ArrayList < String > ();

//Find all dates that are currently selected.  Create a list of these to use later.
List < WebElement > selectedDates = driver.findElements(highlightedDates);
for (WebElement we: selectedDates) {

    collectedDateStrings.add(Utils.convertDateString(we.getAttribute("title")));
}

for (String s: collectedDateStrings) {
    System.out.println("this value is: " + s);
} //this yields nothing
```

**Edit:**
Per some comments I am adding this bit of code:
this is the element I am trying to get the date from:

```
<div class="cvDialogRow" style="width: 149px; text-align: left;"><label id="lblDate0">Wed 06/29/2016<br></label></div
```

This is the command I am using to find the element and make a list:

```
List<WebElement> occurences = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'cvDialogRow')]")).findElements(By.xpath("//label[starts-with(@id, 'lblDate')]"));
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct attribute from the correct element? If you're getting an attribute that doesn't exist it will return an empty string.

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML and the relevant locators in your code above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  The code structure above is ok, but the elements I was looking at had more elemnts listed than I realized.  There should have been 4 elements for 'lblDate' but there were 7.  The first 3 were null so I just removed them as follows:

```
List<WebElement> occurences = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'cvDialogRow')]")).findElements(By.xpath("//label[starts-with(@id, 'lblDate')]"));
    occurences.remove(0);
    occurences.remove(0);
    occurences.remove(0);
```

Now I am looking at the right elements for my list.  Thanks again for the responses.